# import issue when transferred from py2 to py3

Tags: python-3.6, python-2to3

I have following directory structure:

```
content\ip_low_level\unit_tests\dd\dd.py
```

**each directory has __init__.py**

when I'm trying to run dd.py, it is giving following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "content\ip_low_level\unit_tests\dd\dd.py", line 4, in <module>
    from content.ip_low_level.unit_tests.dd.dd  import dd
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'content'
```

> It worked perfectly using python2. But getting issue when trying using
>   Python3. Why py3 can't find this module which is there? **init** is
>   suppose help find the module?

Comment: I went inside the directory where content stays and tried following: py3 -m pip install -e .

Answer (score 0):

I went inside the directory where content statys and tried following.It seems has fixed the issue:

```
py3 -m pip install -e .
```